# Error in Type casting: Python

Tags: python

I have just started to learn python and I am getting the following error for the function I have written. I think it's due to typecast but I am not sure how to correct.

Error I get:

```
File "validate.py", line 23, in keygen
(array3[0]) = int(array2[0]) ^ int(array2[n-1],8)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0xd4d745957e685d08L'
```

Function:

```
def keygen(array2):
    n = len(array2)
    array3[0] = int(array2[0]) ^ int(array2[n-1],8)
    i = 1
    while(i != n):
        array3[i] = array2[i] ^ array3[i-1]
        i = i + 1
    printarray(array3)
```

Here array2 is an array of hexadecimal value as below:

```
 array2: [0xd4d745957e685d08L,
          0x9a542ff214aa011cL,
          0x1289806cf20e724L,
          0x20dd453feea65bf4L,
          0x209ab70c8a12a914L,
          0xa16cde82faf9de54L,
          0x99c60b68361506d4L,
          0x5b98ffaaf450a3d4L,
          0xe5c75e967b0bbbe9L]
```

array3 is an empty array where new values are inserted.

Comment: Your example code does not show this line: `(array3[0]) = int(array2[0]) ^ int(array2[n-1],8)`. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Your error shows a line that isn't in the code you provided. And your `array2` description makes it look like you have an array of `int`s, when you clearly have an array of `str` to get that error. If your problem can't be reproduced, we can't help.

Comment: Where are those `L`s coming from?

Comment: @Kennytm: I have changed my code to the correct one.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Those denote the type "long". it can removed by stripping it off from the right.

Comment: @HarryRiddle My point is, are those coming with the data, or do you add them? I understand that you can strip strings...

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I didn't get you. Do you mean to say that array2 is an array of strings?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: They are coming with the data

Comment: It is clearly a *list* of strings.

Comment: Yeah, well, then strip them off and use `int(my_hex_string.rstrip('L'), 16)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: It gives me the error below: **IndexError: list assignment index out of range**

Comment: @HarryRiddle yes, well, that is a completely unrelated error. You are trying to assign to an index that is out of range... should be obvious from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since array2 contains hex values you have to use int(array2[0], 16) to convert it into integer value. you will need to remove the trailing L from the array or use something like below.

```
array3[0] = int(str(array2[0])[:18], 16) ^ int(str(array2[n-1])[:18], 16)
```